# Custom DropDownList with Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to add a validation support to DropDownList by creating a custom control inheriting from DropDownList:

```
public class MyDropDown: DropDownList, INamingContainer
{
    private const string ValidatorID = "Validator";
    private RequiredFieldValidator _validator;

    protected override ControlCollection CreateControlCollection()
    {
        return new ControlCollection(this);
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        Controls.Clear();

        _validator = new RequiredFieldValidator
        {
            ID = String.Format("{0}_{1}", ID, ValidatorID),
            ControlToValidate = ID,
            InitialValue = String.Empty,
            ErrorMessage = "*",
            ForeColor = Color.Red
        };

        Controls.Add(_validator);
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer);
        _validator.RenderControl(writer);
    }
}
```

My class implements *INamingContainer* because I wanted to avoid naming conflicts.
Unfortunately when I try using this control I get the following exception:

> Unable to find control id 'MDD' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'MDD_Validator'

This is happening beause for *INamingContainer* FindControl(NamingContainerId) returns null.

When I remove *INamingContainer* implementation and set validator ID in the following way:

```
_validator.ID = String.Format("{0}_{1}", ID, ValidatorID);
```

Everything is working fine, and id given to Validator is the same as it would be inside Naming container.

But is there a way to accomplish this **WITH** INamingContainer ?

Comment: instead of `ID` use `this.ClientID` when setting the control to validate...

Comment: It didn't help, the control still cannot be found, only this time there is ClientID in the error message instead of ID

Answer (score 1):

You have the validator inside of the dropdown control. In order for the validator to work it needs to be in the same container as the control it is to validate. What you are going to need to do is rejig the class such that the DropDownList is in the same container as the RequiredFieldValidator. I'd do something like this:

```
public class MyDropDown: WebControl, INamingContainer
{
    private DropDownList _dropDown;
    private RequiredFieldValidator _validator;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        Controls.Clear();

        _dropDown = new DropDownList();
        _dropDown.ID = ID + "_ddl";
        Controls.Add(_dropDown);

        _validator = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        _validator.ID = ID + "_Validator";
        _validator.ControlToValidate = _dropDown.ClientID;
        _validator.InitialValue = String.Empty;
        _validator.ErrorMessage = "*";
        _validator.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        Controls.Add(_validator);
    }

    //etc.
}
```

Info here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controltovalidate.aspx